# JavaScript : CSS & Conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript.

I'm looking forward to trigger an animation when a specific div is visible after a scroll.

I already found a code that code test if a div is visible on screen on not after a scroll but struggle to trigger the animation or css or whatever.

Here's the code i found : http://jsfiddle.net/W33YR/3/

```
var update = function(){
document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = visibleY(document.getElementById('element2')) 
    ? 
    "Inner element is visible" : 
    "Inner element is not visible";};
```

Let's say we want to change the background color of body to black when the element is visible.

How do we get to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is Visible, you want to give a class of `visible` or something similar. That lets you use CSS animations to animate whichever property you want.

You want to use [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Edit: element.classList is supported in many browsers, but not all. See [caniuse.com/#search=classList](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList)
You may want to use [element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

Once this is done, the css is easy. You simply want 2 cases - one to show how the element should look when hidden, and one to what it should look like when visible.

```
#element {
    /* Your styles */
    background-color:#00ff00;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

#element .visible {
    background-color:#0000ff;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

This animates the `background-color` of the element.

Comment: Then simply replace `#element` with `body`

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for actually. Thank you guys for the help !

Comment: Mandatory note: please add in browser compatibility warning for `classList`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
"Inner element is visible" :
```

with

```
document.body.style.background = 'black' :
```

Comment: Hi moonvader, it works fine ! And if i wanted to have some animation when visible, how do you think it'd work?

Comment: OP asked specifically for animations, not a simple color change.

Comment: moonvader: Have an upvote.
@Deep: OP didn't mention animations at all. Just asked how to change the background color to black.

Comment: "I'm looking forward to trigger an animation when a specific div is visible after a scroll." Sorry, what were you saying?

Comment: Uh, use jQuery? It'll solve a lot of animation headaches.

Comment: OP didn't ask for jQuery, and you don't need it at all in this situation.

Comment: @moonvader http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275212/1707126
"it is definitely not acceptable to answer with jQuery when the tag is not present."